# How can I patch out shm in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra, mips, firmware-analysis, router

I've been trying to emulate a Mips binary in qemu, but I kept getting an error for shared memory allocation. I decompiled the function where it happens in Ghidra:

```
local_18 = dm_shmInit(0);
if (local_18 == 0) {
```

```
00405570 3c 1c 00 43     lui        gp,
00405574 27 9c 46 e0     addiu      gp,gp,
00405578 27 bd f9 18     addiu      sp,sp,-
0040557c 8f 99 82 c0     lw         t9,-0x7d40(gp)=>-><EXTERNAL>::dm_shmInit         
00405580 af bc 00 18     sw         gp=>_gp,local_6d0(sp)                            
00405584 af bf 06 e4     sw         ra,local_4(sp)
00405588 af b1 06 e0     sw         s1,local_8(sp)
0040558c af b0 06 dc     sw         s0,local_c(sp)
00405590 a7 a0 00 20     sh         zero,local_6c8(sp)
00405594 a7 a0 00 22     sh         zero,local_6c6(sp)
00405598 a7 a0 00 24     sh         zero,local_6c4(sp)
0040559c a7 a0 00 26     sh         zero,local_6c2(sp)
004055a0 a7 a0 00 28     sh         zero,local_6c0(sp)
004055a4 a7 a0 00 2a     sh         zero,local_6be(sp)
004055a8 a7 a0 00 2c     sh         zero,local_6bc(sp)
004055ac 03 20 f8 09     jalr       t9=><EXTERNAL>::dm_shmInit
```

How can I patch the binary so that `local_18` is set to `0`?